# Как вставить запятые в тексте перед словами?

Tags: c#

Есть текстовый файл, как его подключить к MS Visual Studio и в нем вставлять запятые перед "который", "которая", "которое", "которые", если они не являются первым словом предложения.

Comment: Читать из файла по слову/знаку, если попадается слова из списка, то: а) если до этого был '\n' или '.', то идти дальше или б) вставлять запятую. Ну или просто регулярным выражением, ведь слова в начале с большой буквы =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
string s = <твой текст>;
s = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(s, " котор", ", котор", System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.None);
```

Comment: а если будет тексте будет например: `в котором` как исключить такие слова, чтобы не ставились запятые в данном случае. И если например данные слова являются началом предложения

Comment: Насчет начала предложения, как можно видеть, учтено - " котор" со строчной буквы и регистр при замене учитывается. Насчет "в котор" и т.п. - а самому подумать? Тут ведь не решают задачи за кого-то, тут пути решения подсказывают.